# what changes require in Api.php file to get shipping charges in Android App

Tags: android, magento, soap

we have marketplace **multi vendor/seller** **magento** site. we are doing **Android** App for the site....

we are using custom Shipping method  in our site.

This shipping method is based on "**seller" & "Buyer**" **zip** code. we save seller zip code in Backend. we set the how much shipping charges according to distance in Backend. Once Buyer enter the zip code in shipping address , it will calculate the  shipping charges between seller and buyer based on distance.

This is working fine in site.

But in Android app, we are calling this API to get shipping methods : **shoppingCartShippingList()**

we are getting shipping method , but we are getting shipping charges as zero.
In the following code, i can see , shipping method will set using

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
```

IS the same formula work for APP also for this shipping method as it is based on zip codes?

To work this in App, is we have to change anything in following code as **App is Completely dependent on APIs.....**

/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart/Shipping/APi.php

```
<?php

class Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Shipping_Api extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_ignoredAttributeCodes['quote_shipping_rate'] = array('address_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'rate_id', 'carrier_sort_order');
    }

    /**
     * Set an Shipping Method for Shopping Cart
     *
     * @param  $quoteId
     * @param  $shippingMethod
     * @param  $store
     * @return bool
     */
    public function setShippingMethod($quoteId, $shippingMethod, $store = null)
    {
        $quote = $this->_getQuote($quoteId, $store);

        $quoteShippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        if(is_null($quoteShippingAddress->getId()) ) {
            $this->_fault("shipping_address_is_not_set");
        }

        $rate = $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates()->getShippingRateByCode($shippingMethod);
        if (!$rate) {
            $this->_fault('shipping_method_is_not_available');
        }

        try {
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        } catch(Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('shipping_method_is_not_set', $e->getMessage());
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get list of available shipping methods
     *
     * @param  $quoteId
     * @param  $store
     * @return array
     */
    public function getShippingMethodsList($quoteId, $store=null)
    {
        $quote = $this->_getQuote($quoteId, $store);

        $quoteShippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        if (is_null($quoteShippingAddress->getId())) {
            $this->_fault("shipping_address_is_not_set");
        }

        try {
            $quoteShippingAddress->collectShippingRates()->save();
            $groupedRates = $quoteShippingAddress->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

            $ratesResult = array();
            foreach ($groupedRates as $carrierCode => $rates ) {
                $carrierName = $carrierCode;
                if (!is_null(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title'))) {
                    $carrierName = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title');
                }

                foreach ($rates as $rate) {
                    $rateItem = $this->_getAttributes($rate, "quote_shipping_rate");
                    $rateItem['carrierName'] = $carrierName;
                    $ratesResult[] = $rateItem;
                    unset($rateItem);
                }
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('shipping_methods_list_could_not_be_retrived', $e->getMessage());
        }

        return $ratesResult;
    }


}
```